# Wordpress post text area missing issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have an issue that is in wordpress when i click on add new post button the post form appears it is showing everything on that form except the main content text area it's simply not there. I just updated my wordpress and this happens.

Now I have also downgraded my wordpress to previous version but still same issue.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Try switching to another theme and check if the problem stll exists.

Comment: Yes I already tried that but that page shows this warning
You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts.

Comment: And also when i click on submit button it says Sorry, You are not allowed to edit this page. Now I have no plugins active on my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all your plugins and theme are up to date, compatible with 4.8.1

Flushing any caching plugins you might be running, as well as server and/or browser caches. Not just your browser, but any op cache or content network cache as well such as CloudFlare.

If that does not resolve the issue, try deactivating ALL plugins temporarily to see if this resolves the problem (plugin functions can interfere). If this works, re-activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin(s).

Or

Edit manually wp-config.php file.

Find the line

`define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`
(it is probably true by default installation)

and change in

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false);
```

That might solve your issue. Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Nope didn't work for me. The submit post button on post create page says " "Submit for review". Any Idea what that is

Comment: Page showing this warning as well
You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts.

Comment: And also when i click on submit button it says
Sorry, You are not allowed to edit this page.
Now I have no plugins active on my site.

Comment: Because of might be You are not logged in as an Admin OR Some Plugin confliction OR Database table auto increment may turn off.  Try like  Go to your Phpmyadmin database->select all table and from action choose Repair Tables option But please take your database backup first before doing this.

Comment: Nope repairing those tables also didn't help it. Any other solution that might comes in your mind will be appreciated.

Comment: This problem is related to auto increment in the wp_post table.
Get your user id from the wp_users table and search for the corresponding meta key wp_user_level for your user id inside the wp_usermeta table. The value should be set to 10. OR
If it's really an autoincrement problem, Open your database, select a table wp_posts, click the Structure tab and edit the ID column. There you can enable/disable the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute for this column. Another approach is to export the whole database with the Add AUTO_INCREMENT value selected, delete and re-import the database.

Comment: Thank you so much  Gajjar Chintan this was the issue and by auto-incrementing the ID column in the wp_post table resolved my problem.
"+1"

Comment: If you thought my answer is helpful for you then you can upvote it.

Comment: Sorry completely forgot to do so.